# Git workflow to build a Safari extension

Tags: git, safari, workflow, development-environment, safari-extension

I'm working on a Safari Extension. I use a Dev and Beta branch on Git. Each branch has its own back-end and hosting—so each have their own access, fenced form each other.

When I switch branch: I would like parameters to follow as well. I am using Settings in the extension builder to store the keys I need.

But Safari seems to mess with the plist file switch. It keeps previous parameters at random. Which in turns means I have to spend time making sure things are the way they should.

What is the best setup/workflow to limit messing around with dev and prod parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I can't comment on your workflow for Safari extensions as I have never done it myself...I can tell you the way *I* prefer to work with git...

- I have a master branch, which is always deployable.
- I then have a branch off master (my development branch) which is my development integration branch.
- I then open feature branches off this my development branch(one per feature)
- Releases are done by merging my development branch into master (after lots and lots of testing of course) and then tagging the commit where this was done (I use git flow, so it does most of this for me)
- Hot fix branches are taken off master and worked on. When a hotfix is complete, master is merged in. Then it is merged into my development branch and my master branch.
- As far as your beta branch is concerned, I'm not quite sure why you have this(not being snarky, I genuinely mean that). I would have imagined that the development branch would more or less accomplisht the same thing?

In any case, you might want to check out [Atlassian's great article on git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/). If you use [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) or [Smart Git](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) they both have gitflow support -which is pretty neat.

Comment: thanks for your advices; I have a similar setup—my main issue seems to be when parameters (username, passwords, urls, etc.) for external services are differing on 2 distinct branches.

Comment: Okay firstly you shouldn't have different branches for different environments (that is to say, it shouldn't matter what set of credentials are in there because your app should just swap between them automatically by detecting the environment). Secondly, you shouldn't actually have this info in version control to start with. Consider using environment variables instead.

Comment: precisely; diff branches for different environments: the settings are in the Safari extension plist file, the file is tracked. My issue is when I switch branch: the plist file is switched to the current branch file (that's the intended behaviour), but not in Safari Extension Builder—so it builds with the wrong settings…

Comment: sounds like Safari Extension Builder isn't keeping up with the directory changes. I used to have that problem with Netbeans(it used to get its pants all in a twist if you changed the files underneath it). The only thing I can suggest is that you find some way of refreshing Safari Extension Builder

Comment: only way i found so far is to quit Safari and open it again… :/

Comment: Could be, in any case...have a look at [this](http://juristr.com/blog/2014/09/implementing-the-git-flow/) :)